# Initializing a std::function object from an overloaded function

Tags: c++, overloading, function-pointers

I have a function table of type `map` that maps each binary operator to a function, but I have an overloaded function `Add` that takes two `int` and another version taking two `std::string`. When I pass the function name (`int Add(int, int)`), I get the compiler complains about ambiguity. So I've found a workaround using a pointer initialized explicitly to the version (`int(int, int)`) then pass it.

```
int main(){

    int Add(int, int);
    std::string Add(std::string const&, std::string const&);

    std::map<std::string, std::function<int(int, int)>> binOps;
    //binOps["+"] = Add; // error: amiguous
    int(*pFnAdd)(int, int) = Add;
    binOps["+"] = pFnAdd; // Ok

    binOps["+"] = static_cast<int(*)(int, int)> (Add); // OK?
    std::cout << binOps["+"](10, 20) << '\n'; // ok 30. I should use binOps.find rather than []

}
```

- The code works fine with disambiguating the usage of `Add` so is my second version that passes a temporary pointer to `int Add(int, int)` is OK or I should pass a named-pointer to function like `pFnAdd`?

Comment: You obtain the same address in both cases. So any answer is going to be majorly about what folks find more pleasing to read (which is opinion based).

Comment: The explicit type cast is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

This question is opinion-based ... but, I mean, clearly the explicit cast is better in the sense that I see no reason to *not* just do that.